# Annotated Service bean is not instantiating as dependent bean is declated in xml file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement like this.

I need to autowire a bean which is declared in `XML(X-servlet)` file and my current class is annotated with `@Service`. So, I am getting began creating exception. As by the time of creating annotated bean it couldn't find bean declared in XML. How do I get rid of this?

Here is the sample code snippet.

```
<bean id="checkingProcesService" class       ="com.optival.pos.service.CheckingProcesServiceImpl">
    <property name="barcodeDao">
        <ref bean="barcodeDao"/>
    </property>
    <property name="readonlyBarcodeDao">
        <ref bean="readonlyBarcodeDao"/>
    </property>
    <property name="ritemedBarcodeDao">
        <ref bean="rightMedBarcodeDao"/>
    </property>
    <property name="posJdbcDao">
        <ref bean="jdbcDao"/>
    </property>
    <property name="readonlyPosJdbcDao">
        <ref bean="readonlyJdbcDao"/>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMedJdbcDao">
        <ref bean="rightMedJdbcDao"/>
    </property>
    <property name="newPosJDBCDao">
        <ref bean="newjdbcDao"/>
    </property>
    <property name="newReadonlyPosJdbcDao">
        <ref bean="newreadonlyJdbcDao"/>
    </property>
</bean>

@Service
public class OpticalOrderServiceImpl implements OpticalOrderService {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OpticalOrderServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    CheckingProcesService checkingProcesService
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what i read there i assume you have the following:

Bean declaration in a XML
Service that calls the Bean declared in the XML

If that is the case then you need to make sure you have included your xml file with bean(s) in your dispatcher-servlet.xml (whatever you have called it in your file) or at least you are scanning the file so that it gets picked up.

If you want please add your code for dispatcher-servlet.xml and i'll try help further.

Comment: thnx for concern....actually existing bean is declared in dispatcher-server.xml and now i'm writing a class with @Service annotation. In my class i want to inject bean declared in xml file.and in xml file component scan is enabled...

Comment: Ok you need to paste in the exception that you are getting in the main question